# Relationship between a set difference and Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider these following sets $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$.
Let $r=(m,n)$ be an ordered pair so that:

$$r \, \in \, (A \times B) \setminus (C \times D)$$

Are these following steps correct?

$$\Rightarrow r \in (A \times B) \wedge r \not\in (C \times D)
\Rightarrow r \in (A \times B) \wedge r \in (C \times D)^\prime$$

$$\Rightarrow m \in A \wedge n \in B \wedge m \in C^\prime \wedge n \in D^\prime$$

Comment: I am sorry I tried to type in math font but failed...

Comment: Your last step is not correct. $(m, n)$ is not in $C \times D$. It means either $m$ is not in $C$ **or** $n$ is not in $D$.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh I am trying to get all and operators here. Can you help?

Comment: Can you use the NOT operator to get AND operators?